# Disabling a jToggleButton

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

Hey guys so I'm making this simple movie ticketing system
My program flow is as follow and all pages are in different JFrames: Main Menu>Choose Day>Select movie>select seat>back to MainMenu

I'm using `JToggle` in the seat chooser. Is it possible to disable the toggle button throughout entire execution once selected? I'm using  `JToggleButton.setEnabled(false);` but everytime I go back to menu and come back to seat chooser,the button is still not disabled .what I want to do is to have it disable even after I'm back to MainMenu, so when I go back to seat chooser, I can't select this seat anymore.

Below are some codes in it:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    this.setVisible(false);
    MainSelection s =  new MainSelection();
    s.setVisible(true);

     if(jToggleButton1.isSelected())

    {
        jToggleButton1.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if(jToggleButton2.isSelected())

    {
        jToggleButton2.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if(jToggleButton3.isSelected())

    {
        jToggleButton3.setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

Please check it out

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `JToggleButton`'s "enabled" property most probably doesn't reset itself to `true` when you set it to `false`. I think that you actually are looking at an **other** `JToggleButton`'s instance. Maybe you re-create it every time you access the "select seat" GUI?
In that case, what you want is to dissociate the **application-data** (where you have the information about which seat are already reserved etc) from the **user interface**.

A good way to do so, I believe, is to work with the **Model-View-Controller** pattern.
Let me introduce you to this design pattern:

- the **Model** holds your application data (e.g., could be a `Set<Seat>`)
- the **View** is use to display your data (i.e. your `JToggleButton`)
- the **Controller** is the entry point from which your Model is updated (in your case, those are also the `JToggleButton`)

You can read more about it there: [MVC Pattern - tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm).

Basically, instead of creating a new "empty" **View** every time, you want to load it with the values contained by your data container (the **Model**). Then, when you click on some `JToggleButton` that represents a seat (a **Controller**), you don't directly change the state of the button, but you just simply update your **Model** to toggle the state (reserved or not) of your seat. Then, each time the **Model** is updated, your **View** refreshes using the new data available. That's it!

```
+--------------------------------------+
|    +-----------+                     |
|    |   Model   <-------+             |
|    +-----v-----+       |             |
|          |             |             |
|          |             |             |
|    +-----v---+---------^----------+  |
|    |  View   |     Controller     |  |
|    +---------+--------------------+  |
|                                      |
+---------- Your application ----------+
```

Feel free to ask more about it, it might seem really like a lot to change but it comes with many interesting design features :)
Especially if you need to have another **View** (for example, a `File` in which you would like to save your data every time a change is made)!